# How can I make a checkbox checked or not checked depending on what the value is in the database

Tags: php, laravel-5

So, I have this in my `edit.blade.php`

```
<div class="form-check disabled">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="hidden" value='0' name="is_default">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value='1' name="is_default">
        Default Variant
    </label>
</div>
```

and I have an `is_default` column in my database which has the values of either 0 or 1 depending if the checkbox is checked or not.

Now, I want to create an edit page and I want to show if that if `is_default` value is 1 then the checkbox should be checked, else it will be unchecked.

the value of `is_default` is represented as `value="{{ $variant->is_default }}"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try this

In edit.blade.php

```
<div class="form-check disabled">
<label class="form-check-label">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value='1' name="is_default" {{ (isset($variant->is_default) && !empty($variant->is_default))?'checked':'' }}>
    Default Variant
</label>
</div>
```

in controller check for

```
<?php
.....
$is_default = isset($_POST['is_default'])?1:0;
// If checkbox is checked then isset will become true else false
// Update the db
....
?>
```

I hope this will help you... Happy Coding:)

Comment: Thank you very much! Works like charm! :)